# CSRF is still invalid after setting AJAX SETUP

Tags: jquery, ajax, cookies

I am trying to make a POST request in AJAX but keep getting CSRF invalid error.
I've configured the csrf using this
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax

When I accessed the url, I got a csrf:
Cookie:sessionid=jo35benob5f42oj; csrftoken=sOahnxw8fd1rBxQSuEi2xcKD7DTl

Then I made a POST to other site from AJAX, got CSRF error.

The request header is:
Cookie:sessionid=jo35benob5f42oj; csrftoken=sOahnxw8fd1rBxQSuEi2xcKD7DTl

The two CSRF tokens were identical, I don't see why the 403 came.
Thank you!